# openMP reduction and thread number control

Tags: openmp

I use OpenMP as:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:average_stroke_width)
for(int i = 0; i < GB_name.size(); ++i) {...}
```

I know I can use :

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread)
for(int index = 0; index < GB_name.size(); ++index){...}
```

How can I control the thread number when I use reduction?

Comment: You mean you want to set how many threads participate in the reduction procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I control the thread number when I use reduction?

Both clauses can be used togehter:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:average_stroke_width) num_threads(thread)
for(int i = 0; i < GB_name.size(); ++i) {...}
```

Note that `reduction` involves all threads, so you cannot have a parallel loop with 8 threads and then perform a reduction with 4 threads only. Reduction combines the local values in all threads and therefore all of them need to participate.